What does the Rust move keyword on a closure actually do?
The Rust documentation for move tells us this:

Capture a closure's environment by value. move converts any variables captured by reference or mutable reference to variables captured by value.

My initial interpretation of this was that
move || {
    thread_function(&flag, &some_data);
}

(effectively) becomes translated instead to
|| {
    thread_function(flag, some_data);
}

In other words, the variables which were references to something have been converted into "move by value"s.
However, this doesn't seem to make much sense.
If we think about what a closure is, a reasonable mental model is that a closure is syntactic sugar for a functor.
A functor is going to be something like a struct, where the members of the struct are the arguments in the capture list of the closure.
For example, a reasonable mental model for
let x
let y
let z
let lambda = || { println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, z); }

might be something like
struct lambda {
    x,
    y,
    z,
}

impl Fn for lambda { ... }

The documentation explains that capturing of local variables is by reference if possible, or by mutable reference if a mutable reference is required.
There are three modes by which a variable could be captured.

by value (moved): lambda = || { /*x: Type*/ }
by reference: lambda = || { /*y: &Type*/ }
by mutable reference lambda = || { /*z: &mut Type*/ }

With the "by reference" option being preferred when possible, and the "by mutable reference" being chosen when by reference is not possible because mutability is required.
However, this leaves one unexplained option - "by value".
For each of the 3 cases, we could imagine a struct being created with the appropriate member variable type.
struct {
    x: Type,
    y: &Type,
    z: &mut Type,
}

Given this model, if move causes the lambda to capture used locals by value, then it may be reasonable to assume that captures by reference are converted into captures by value, and that captures by mutable reference are converted to captures by mutable value.
This also doesn't seem to be quite right - what would the difference between capturing by "value" and capturing by "mutable value" be? Value already affords full ownership, so this also seems nonsencial.
So the question is, what exactly does move do when applied to a lambda?

As with your other question, the reference may provide the (simple) answer: The compiler does not take surrounding code into account, such as the lifetimes of involved variables, or of the closure itself. If the move keyword is used, then all captures are by move or, for Copy types, by copy, regardless of whether a borrow would work. Using move does not change thread_function(&flag) to thread_function(flag), but it does force moving flag into the closure's state, where it is then borrowed. In the example, this does allow for the closure to be moved, taking flag alongside with it.

You have very good intuition. It seems that the word "converts" is very unfortunate, and that it caused more misunderstanding than it helped to explain anything. You are right, that compiler under the hood defines some anonymous struct for each closure and implement appropriate Fn* traits for it. The types of its fields will depend on the type of the closure.
Rust have two types of closures. Those that capture environment by reference (shared or mutable/exclusive depending on usage), and those that capture by value/move. You cannot specify particular strategy for one variable. In C++ you can have lambda that captures everything by reference [&](){ ... }, or by copy [=](){ ... }. And in Rust you can either capture all variables by reference, or move all of them to the closure.
Consider following example, which does not compile:
fn own(_: Box<i32>) {}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(1);
    let y = Box::new(1);
    
    (move || {
        own(x);
        println!("{y}");
    })();
    
    own(y);
}

Immediately invoked closure takes ownership of both x and y. Even though we could print y with only a shared reference, the move closure captured it. Hence compilation error:
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `y`
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
5  |     let y = Box::new(1);
   |         - move occurs because `y` has type `Box<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
6  |     
7  |     (move || {
   |      ------- value moved into closure here
8  |         own(x);
9  |         println!("{y}");
   |                    - variable moved due to use in closure
...
12 |     own(y);
   |         ^ value used here after move

So now the question is: is there a walk-around of this limitation? And yes. Though this is a little cumbersome you can introduce a new scope and shadow those variables, that you would wish to capture by reference. For example:
fn own(_: Box<i32>) {}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(1);
    let y = Box::new(1);
    
    {
        let y = &y;
        (move || {
            own(x);
            println!("{y}");
        })();
    }
    
    own(y);
}

Here we shadow y with a reference to itself. What is important is that the type of closure did not change! It still captured everything by move. But it captured x: Box<i32> and y: &Box<i32>. So in the end, all that move does, is that it tells the compiler to capture all used variables by move/ownership. There is no "conversion".

Most of it was explained in Aleksander Krauze’s answer, but here's one more example
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello world!");
    let closure = || println!("{s}");

    std::thread::spawn(closure);
}

the closure captures s by reference, that's the "default". But then the closure itself is being moved into another thread to be invoked there. If you try to compile it, you'll get
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `s`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/main.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     let closure = || println!("{s}");
  |                   ^^            - `s` is borrowed here
  |                   |
  |                   may outlive borrowed value `s`

The problem is, as you have correctly surmised, rust creates opaque type for closure which "contains" captured values. But those captures are references by default. So what we have is essentially something like this
struct Closure<'a> { s: &'a String }

and if we move it to another thread, we might end up with reference that outlives the referenced value (a dangling pointer), if for example thread owning s drops it before the reference to s is used in closure call. And that is not allowed in safe rust, so the borrow checker rejects this code.
For scenarios like this, the move semantics exist, it allows us to force the captured value to be owned by closure, so that the closure itself can then be safely moved.
